# Oracle: Sort results by date with subgroup by the same date

Tags: oracle, sorting, date, sql-order-by

I need to sort my overall results by the create date column below, but have them grouped together by their application id, with those subgroups sorted by the same date like this:

```
APPLICATION_ID  STATUS  CREATE_DATE
12345           REC     01-06-2017
12345           PRO     02-06-2017
12345           DEL     03-06-2017
12746           REC     02-06-2017
12746           REC     05-06-2017
12743           DEL     04-06-2017
12743           PRO     09-06-2017
12743           PRO     11-06-2017
```

APPLICATION_ID is a datatype VARCHAR2 and CREATE_DATE is type DATE. Neither columns are nullable.

I do not have access to other relevant tables within the schema, I can only query this one.
Sorting with the below query doesn't give the overall date order I need.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY APPLICATION_ID, CREATE_DATE;
```

Example output:

```
APPLICATION_ID  STATUS  CREATE_DATE
10603           REC     15-06-2017
10603           PRO     15-06-2017
10603           DEL     22-06-2017
11251           REC     21-06-2017
11251           REC     21-06-2017
11894           DEL     02-06-2017
11894           PRO     05-06-2017
11894           PRO     06-06-2017
```

In the above, I'm trying to get the order to be 11894 records first, then 10603, then 11251

Comment: Well, what is the output you are getting?  Please show it

Comment: We need relevant datamodel parts to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order by applications minumum create date then consider the following:

```
with MY_TABLE as (
  select 12746 APPLICATION_ID, 'REC' STATUS, date '2017-06-02' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12746 APPLICATION_ID, 'REC' STATUS, date '2017-06-05' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12743 APPLICATION_ID, 'DEL' STATUS, date '2017-06-04' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12743 APPLICATION_ID, 'PRO' STATUS, date '2017-06-09' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12743 APPLICATION_ID, 'PRO' STATUS, date '2017-06-11' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12345 APPLICATION_ID, 'REC' STATUS, date '2017-06-01' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12345 APPLICATION_ID, 'PRO' STATUS, date '2017-06-02' CREATE_DATE from dual union all
  select 12345 APPLICATION_ID, 'DEL' STATUS, date '2017-06-03' CREATE_DATE from dual
)
select *
from   MY_TABLE 
order by min(create_date) over(partition by APPLICATION_ID), APPLICATION_ID, CREATE_DATE
```

It creates the output you listed.